# SemanticImport cannot find files

Tags: import

I have the following, simple code I am trying to execute:

```
SemanticImport["data.csv" <|2 -> String, 3 -> Integer|>]
```

Which gives me the following error:

> SemanticImport: File not found during SemanticImport

When using the simple "Import" function, it works perfectly.

Has anybody encountered this error before and knows the Solution? I am using Windows 10 as well as Mathematica 11.2 Student Edition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't you missing `,` between arguments?